# Java adding images from a URL into my JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, url, jpanel

I know that there is plenty of questions and answers already posted regarding this issue but I believe my situation has a bit of a twist. I have a JPanel inside a JFrame; the Jpanel has a painted image background of a network map. I created a layout using MigLayout. Inside the cells of this layout I want to display images that I get from a url. The twist is that further down in my project, I want to be able to refresh that image every 5 seconds or so.

That being said, is there a specific way I should pursue in adding my images in order to make it easy on myself later on int he project to refresh those images every 5 seconds?

If I'm lacking any necessary additional information, please let me know.

Comment: *"I want to display images that I get from a url"*  What is the content of the images?  What is a typical URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using a grid of JLabels and swapping ImageIcons when desired using the JLabel `setIcon(Icon icon)` method. To do something like this every 5 seconds, consider using a Swing Timer. Or if you are going to download an image every xxx seconds, then a `SwingWorker<Void, ImageIcon>`.

If this doesn't help, then please specify exactly where you may be stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Extending on HovercraftFullOfEels suggestions, I would create a custom `Component` (probably a `JLabel` in this case).

I would use a `javax.swing.Timer` in each, set to repeat each 5 seconds, that would execute a download request. The problem here is;

1. It may cause a drain on your systems resources if you have lots of images, with each component requesting an individual download
2. The time it takes to down each image might take longer then 5 seconds. What would you do in that case?

The other approach is to have a centralised queue that is responsible for processing the download requests.  This could either be automated (ie, you register you `Component` to it and it decides when it should be updated) or dumb, you add a request when ever you want to.

In the automated model, you gain greater control over resource management.

In this case I'd be tempted to use something like a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to manage the download tasks.  The basic idea would be, that at a given time in the future (5 seconds), the download task would execute, this would download the image and apply it to the `Component`, it would then register a new download request back onto the `ScheduledExecutorService`

This approach allows you to control the number of threads been created by the systemas well as modify the time between request.

In the dumb model, I'd probably use a combination of `javax.swing.Timer` & a [ExectutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (probably a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)).  The timer would be associated with each `Component`, when it fires, it puts a new request onto the dumb queue.  The dumb queue,at some time in the future would download the image & return it to the `Component`.

The major problem I see with this, is it would be possible for a component to request a new image before the previous request has completed. While there are techniques you can employ to trap these conditions, it would be simplier and easier to use the smart queue idea

All these ideas take advantage of Java's `Thread` capabilities, in this case it would very important that you understand the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) & how to handle [Concurrency in Swing](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=swing%20event%20dispatch%20thread&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CF4QFjAB&url=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html&ei=QvQiUOfFJMeQiAfTnYG4Dw&usg=AFQjCNGcXdzVRzVPo6KM1UD_2Png8yGeZg&sig2=vM6NecUriJrPPWsAbjfkVg)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEes you gave me the idea ;)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your time and effort on that. I have never heard of the Event Dispatching Thread and I don't know how to handle concurrency in Swing so I am going to read up on those over the next day or so. In the mean time, Im curious if it makes a difference to tell you that the images I am taking from a url are simple small images, no bigger that 300x100 px; also the refresh time might extend to 5 minutes (depending on what my boss decides)

Comment: @Pat sure, image size will make a difference, but imagine if your application wants to request 100's or 1000's of images off the server, or you have 10's of the applications running on the network all request images at the same time, that's a significant load on the network & server, not to mention the load on memory and CPU usage for the PC having to handle those streams and load the images into memory.  Just something to keep in mind ;)

Answer (score 2):

If the '5 second images' are showing 'network status updates' or similar, the app. would probably be better off (bandwidth wise, as well as to avoid image caching) getting the updates as text (or objects etc.) then creating an appropriate image and calling for a repaint if needed.